# Is there any way to make a custom field for a post only if the author is a certain user?

Tags: custom-field, advanced-custom-fields

In short, when editing a post, if the author is set to say... user ID #47... I want another text field to come up to add to the post meta for this post.

I have ACF Pro, but I'm not seeing that as an option with it.

If it matters and if there's another solution... the issue is that occasionally posts will have authors who aren't WP Users, and we want one user to encompass them all, but have a text field for the author's name.

Answer (score 0):

This is what You are looking for

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/custom-location-rules/